# How to make a variable defined in a matlab function accessible outside the function

Tags: matlab

I have built a matlab function and I want to access one of its variables ,say x in the workspace. If I write x in the workspace it says Undefined function or variable "x"

Comment: You can have the function return the variable you want in the workspace (`x=myFunction(input)`). Read the [documentation on function declaration](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html).

Comment: If you want that for debugging, set a breakpoint within the function

Answer (score 1):

Using the `global` modifier will definitely make your variable visible to the workspace, but it will also make it visible to any other function you call that happens to use that variable name. So if you insist on doing it this way, make sure that your variable name is unique.

A better way, in my opinion, is to pass back the value of the variable as a return value from the function, though this may require changes to calling functions.

Other options are detailed here:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/share-data-between-workspaces.html